# Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: c++, tensorflow, ssl, grpc

I am new to grpc and tensorflow model server. I have built tensorflow model server (TF2.2) from source using bazel. I am trying to use tensorflow model server with SSL authentication. And I am not able to communicate properly between client and server.
Basically I am trying to test my TFserver with the help of two clients (for eg client A and client B, located at two different machines). Client A uses grpc with default SSL (boring SSL), and client B uses GRPC with OpenSSL 1.1.1g version. My TFserver is able to communicate with Client A but not with Client B. both the client code is written in C++. and both code is identical just the SSL version is different.

I have following questions :

1. I had tensorflow model server binary for tf1.x version as well. And in that binary I have these parameters (--enable_secure, --pkcs_password_encrypted, --pkcs_store_path, --pkcs_password_keystore_path, --enable_client_auth and --ssl_config_file) for implementing SSL Auth. but when I built TF2.2 model serving binary I only get --ssl_config_file parameter in it. So my question is did I do something wrong or forgot to pass some argument while building the TF serving?
2. Whenever I start my tensorflow model server with --ssl_config_file param it is throwing this error :

   **E1017 00:51:53.358762382    5881 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER**

   And this error is coming iteratively after every 5-10 seconds even before my client sends request to server. And as I have mentioned earlier that I am able to communicate with client A i.e. the one having GRPC with default SSL version (boringSSL) even after getting this error on TF model server side. But not able to communicate with client B where I have built GRPC with OpenSSL-1.1.1g version. What could be the possible reason?
3. I want to know, how I can get the logs on TFmodel server side? I am just getting startup log and the error log, but not getting the logs when client request to the server. I have tried with -v=1, but it did not work for me.

I am posting the command that I am using to start the server and server startup log with the error :

```
Command : 
/home/user/TFSERVING/bin/tensorflow_model_server --port=9002 --model_config_file=/home/user/model_config.conf -v=1 --ssl_config_file=/home/user/TFSERVING/conf/tf_ssl.conf

server starting log : 
.............................
.............................
I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2020-10-17 01:51:46.912960: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:295] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: /home/dipesh/models/dnn_for_cdssm/1
2020-10-17 01:51:46.916942: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:234] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2020-10-17 01:51:46.940462: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:183] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: /home/user/models/dnn_for_cdssm/1
2020-10-17 01:51:46.947514: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:364] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 36559 microseconds.
2020-10-17 01:51:46.948348: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:105] No warmup data file found at /home/user/models/dnn_for_cdssm/1/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2020-10-17 01:51:46.949083: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:87] Successfully loaded servable version {name: dnn_for_cdssm version: 1}
2020-10-17 01:51:46.955075: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:355] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:9002 ...
E1017 01:55:30.274185306   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:55:50.273963581   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:56:10.273677580   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:56:30.273541640   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:56:50.273330934   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:57:05.273176164   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:57:20.273020963   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:57:40.272633395   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E1017 01:57:55.272573695   11400 ssl_transport_security.cc:1285] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
```

I know, I have asked so many questions but I am completely lost in making the secure connection between my client and TF Server. So I want to cover all the possible reasons that might have gone wrong. Please help me to get this done.

If anyone need any clarification please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the underlying SSL library.
Are you using TLS or mTLS between client and server?
Do you have client side log as well?

I am not familiar with TF parameters, e.g., --pkcs_password_encrypted. gRPC does not support password encrypted keys.